# detecting edge direction using Julia-language

Tags: edge-detection, canny-edge-detector

Let say we have following image:

[image]

made with following Julia-code:

```
using Images
using PyPlot
using ImageFiltering

function chessboardimg(m::Int, n::Int, blkwidth::Int, blkheight::Int, )
  img = zeros(m, n)

  togglex = true
  toggley = !togglex
  for i=1:m
    togglex = true
    for j=1:n
      img[i, j] = abs(togglex - toggley)
      if j % blkwidth <= 0
        togglex = !togglex
      end
    end
    if i % blkheight <= 0
      toggley = !toggley
    end
  end
  return img
end

### creating image ####
img1 = transpose(triu(ones(20, 20)))
img2 = chessboardimg(20, 20, 10, 10)
img = [img1 img2]
```

Now i want to get the edge directions in this image as below:

```
gx, gy = imgradients(img)
mag, grad_angle = magnitude_phase(gx, gy)
grad_angle *= 180 / pi
imshow(grad_angle, "gray", interpolation="none")
```

These are the images of each calculated step:

[image]

as you can see in the "Gradient Direction"-image twoh vertical lines are missing.
which should actually indicate the transition from black to white region in the y-direction.

1) what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's the x- and what's the y-axis in your plots? It looks like you swapped the plots that say "y derivative" and "x derivative"

Comment: more importantly, are you sure that it's wrong that this line is missing? does `imshow` deal with the values you feed it like you *think* it should do it, or does it just behave like it's *specified* to deal with them?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry the plot was swapped! i edited again! independently from $imshow$ the values for two transitions are missing in the "Gradient Direction"-Matrix.

Comment: are you 100% sure? these don't happen to be the one where angle is negative?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes i just checked the whole Gradient-Direction-Matrix these transitions are not in the matrix, not even as a $\pm180; deg$ !

Comment: Oh wait. I'm stupid. What *is* the angle of "there's no edge here"? Which direction correspondends to that?

Answer (score 1):

The edges "missing" from the picture are actually those that have angle=0; which is the same as the phase you get for "there's no edge here".

So, nothing wrong.

Comment: exactly correct and that is why i am saying that this is wrong because, there are two vertical transitions as you see in x-derivative (those marked with white line in x-derivative) which have the value $ \frac{\partial{I}}{\partial{x}}(i,j)= 1.0 $ correspending values in y-derivative image are  $ \frac{\partial{I}}{\partial{y}}(i,j)= 0.0 $ which yields to $\theta=atan2(0,1) = 0$ so you can not distinguish betwenn regions with no edge and those with vertical edges!

Comment: I don't understand, @arashjavan, are you agreeing with me or contradicting me?

Comment: actually both ;), i agree with you in case that where angle is 0 we have an horizontally running edge beacue in that case you have $\theta=atan2(1,0)=0$. And i do not agree with you because there is still an edge there but because of the nature of $atan2$ which gives you $0$ for both $$\theta=atan2(0,0)=atan2(1,0)=0$$ and ecatly here we are loosing those edges.

Comment: @arashjavan you're mixing up directions again. $\text{atan2}(1,0)\ne 0$. Instead, $0=\text{atan2}(0,0) = \text{atan2}(0,\alpha),\,\alpha\ge0$ (but $\text{atan2}(0,-\alpha) \ne 0$, too).

Comment: sorry for the typo, of course i meant $atan2(0,\alpha)=0=atan2(0,0)$, which as you wrote too would mean that we do lose edges transition from $0 \rightarrow 1$ in the $x$-Direction. right?